# Equals two object open classes

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main()
{
    println(A() == B())
}

open class A
open class B
```

Why the сompiler doesn't show an error on equals? If the classes are not open, there is an error `Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'A' and 'B'`.

Comment: There is a discussion [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/strange-behavior-with-equality-checking/7289), but it's only, well, a discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Based on my understanding of https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/strange-behavior-with-equality-checking/7289/2)

For classes, calling `x == y` is equal to calling `x.equals(y)`. By default, `equals()` is a reference equality: each object is only equal to itself.

Now, consider the cases:

1. If both classes are not open, then their `equals()` can't change. Therefore, the result of comparison is always `false`. Since it's likely an unintended behavior, the compiler shows an error.
2. If exactly one class is open, then its subclasses can override its `equals()` behavior.
   One may think that now the condition `x == y` may potentially become true. However, equality must satisfy some properties, and one of them is **symmetry**: result of `x == y` must be the same as `y == x`. Since the second class can't override its `equals()` behavior, the condition is still always `false`.
3. If both classes are open, then both their subclasses may override `equals()` so that it becomes `true` without violating any properties of `equals()`.

Comment: One more point. We can see that a subclass is not used, even though the classes are open. The compiler must not be checking for that.

Comment: But what if the === operator is used? Compiler still no show error

Comment: @Roman, That I don't know. Probably because they use the same check for `==` and `===`? I would suggest reporting this to JetBrains, but they won't change it anyway since it'll break the existing code.